# Javascript Class missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a class and add several settings/const's.

I keep getting this error and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Error: `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement[Learn More]  index.html:18:31`

Here's the code:

```
class myClass {
 constructor() {
  this.settings: {
    age: 25,
    favAnimal: 'dog'
  }
 }
 myFunction() {
   console.log("say something");
 } 
}

var aClass = new myClass("hello");
aClass.myFunction();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `=` instead of `:`, since you are assigning an object to a variable.

```js
class myClass {
  constructor() {
    this.settings = {
      age: 25,
      favAnimal: 'dog'
    }
  }
  myFunction() {
    console.log("say something");
  }
}

var aClass = new myClass("hello");
aClass.myFunction();
```

Comment: Good eyes! Beat me by a second!